# My app is crashing because of the "addView": the error on it is: Method invocation may produce nullPointException

Tags: java

```
// *** See the error marked below ***

package com.example.android.miwok;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NumbersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_numbers);

        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

        words.add(0,"One");
        words.add(1, "Two");
        words.add(2, "Three");
        words.add(3,"Four");
        words.add(4,"Five");
        words.add(5,"Six");
        words.add(6,"Seven");
        words.add(7,"Eight");
        words.add(8,"Nine");
        words.add(9,"Ten");

        LinearLayout rootView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootView);

        TextView wordsView = new TextView(this);
        wordsView.setText(words.get(0));

        // ***
        // Here is the addView method that's not working:
        // ***

        rootView.addView(wordsView);

    }
}
```

I don't know why this crash is happening. When I want to test my app, it crashes and says that it has stopped and when I remove the code from "calling the linear layout" to "after the "rootView.addView(wordsView);" "

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your code:

Java code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

        words.add(0,"One");
        words.add(1,"Two");
        words.add(2,"Three");
        words.add(3,"Four");
        words.add(4,"Five");
        words.add(5,"Six");
        words.add(6,"Seven");
        words.add(7,"Eight");
        words.add(8,"Nine");
        words.add(9,"Ten");

        LinearLayout rootView = findViewById(R.id.layout);

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText(words.get(0));

        rootView.addView(textView);

    }
}
```

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

As you can see the code works fine for me. Also you should provide your XML.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! i cleaned and then rebuilt the project. Now it works fine.